# Springer Humanities Bibtex

Tags: bibtex

it looks like there is no Springer bibtex style for their humanities bibliography (e.g. they want full first names!)  Has anyone seen or written one?

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! Could you provide an example for such a bibliography? Perhaps there is a similar style that could be edited to it or even used out-of-the-box

Comment: Put `\bibliographystyle{chicago}` before your `\bibliography` command. Do you use `biblatex`? You should read http://www.ctan.org/pkg/biblatex-chicago then.

Comment: I was using bibtex but am switching over to try biblatex.  Why don't you post this as an answer instead of a comment, what if just inserting that fixes it?  You're clearer / more specific than the only answer so far.

Comment: Argh, biblatex is not tolerant of the fact I use my bibtex file for all kinds of notes, many not properly formatted.  But just using chicago.bst seems well out of date.

Answer (score 2):

Springer writes in its [Key_Style_Points_HumanitiesRef.pdf](http://www.springer.com/cda/content/document/cda_downloaddocument/Key_Style_Points_HumanitiesRef.pdf?SGWID=0-0-45-1330673-0) (0.4 MB):

> This style is based on the reference list style as suggested by the
>   Chicago Manual of Style (15th edn.). In order to facilitate automated
>   processing, the citation of Internet publications has been modified
>   and follows the standard structure of journal and book citations.

If you do not need any internet publications in your reference, you will be safe to use the [Chicago style](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/biblatex-chicago). If you use online references and they appear different to the ones shown in the above PDF, you should show an MWE with that special case here and someone will try to fix that.

PS: As Springer is quite practised in LaTeX, it might also help to write an email and to ask for a template (some book of your taste without content for example).